# How can I define NaN in LaTeX3

Tags: programming, latex3, expl3, l3fp

LaTeX3 `l3fp` offers a way to check if a variable has a an infinite value. The following code defines a number and then sets its value to π/2. It then calculates tan(π/2) to get a large result.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \fp_new:N \mynumber
  \fp_new:N \pi_half
  \fp_div:Nn \pi_half{\c_pi_fp/2}
  \fp_tan:Nn  \mynumber{\pi_half}
  \texttt{\mynumber}\\

  \fp_if_infinity:NTF \c_infinity_fp {NaN}{Do~something~with~\number}\\

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

In many languages the indeterminate form is normally indicated by [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) what would be a good strategy to define a macro to test for this in `expl3` for all cases of `NaN`, such as division by zero etc?

Comment: As I've said in my updated answer, I think this actually needs some revision.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The FPU for LaTeX3 has undergone some major changes. Up to the version included in the DVD of TeX Live 2012 (mid-June 2012) the 'old' FPU worked one way. The improved FPU, available from the development repository and scheduled for release to CTAN some time in late June 2012, is expandable and features a number of improvements.

### Updated (expandable) FPU answer

The new FPU recognises the 'not a number' concept

```
\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { nan }
```

NaN is not equal to any value, not even another NaN: this is the standard approach in many languages. Thus

```
\fp_compare:nNnTF { nan } = { nan } { \TRUE } { \FALSE }
```

is FALSE.

### Original (non-expandable) FPU answer

There are currently special markers in `expl3` for infinite and undefined results, `\c_infinite_fp` and `\c_undefined_fp`. Division by exactly zero is undefined:

```
\fp_div:Nn \l_my_fp { 0 }
\fp_if_undefined:NTF \l_my_fp { TRUE } { FALSE }
```

gives `TRUE`.

Thinking about this again, I notice that the tangent of π/2 should not actually be infinite as it does not have a limit (thinking about the various tests for limits of series). I suspect this should be altered: expect the next `expl3` update to improve in this area.

Comment: @Joseph Thanks! I was just thinking of something such as `fp_if_NaN`, but as you say you covered the bases. Will take a look at the LaTeX-L list.

Comment: @Yiannis: I've just checked in a change so that both division by zero and tan(π/2) will give `\c_undefined_fp` as  result, which is tested for using `\fp_if_undefined:N(TF)`. This will go to CTAN in a moment.

Comment: @Joseph Good correction as the domain of the inverse tangent function is all real numbers, but neither -infinity nor infinity is included in that set.

Comment: @Yiannis: Well, at the moment I've not implemented arctan! (Do say if it's needed and I'll get on with it.)

Comment: @Joseph dying for a `pow` function :)

Comment: @Joseph: Matlab tells me that `tand(90)` is indeed `Inf` (but `tan(pi/2)` is some large number due to machine precision of `pi`). Similarly `1/0` should also be infinity? Matlab examples for `NaN` include `0/0` and `Inf-Inf`.

Comment: @Will: Using the limit definition, tan(pi/2) is not defined as you can define series tending to tan(pi/2) which go to +inf approached from one side and -inf approached from the other (I should have spotted this earlier, but didn't work it through until Yiannis asked his question). Most mathematics texts agree that division by zero is an undefined operation, rather than having an infinite result, as it is not something that can be defined as a limit. (The related function x^-1 is undefined at zero as like tan(pi/2) it tends to +inf from one direction and -inf from the other.)

Comment: @Joseph: As Will pointed out, `tan(pi/2)` can't really give something undefined if `pi/2` is stored as a number. Incidentally, as a mathematician I have to insist that for the limit definition you use _sequences_, not series. As for `1/0`, this is _sometimes_ `\infty` in mathematics, but only in special contexts. In general it should indeed be undefined, as you reasoned.

Comment: @Hendrik: The limitation that we are always talking about machine numbers is of course always present. As with any numerical implementation, `l3fp` has to pick some value 'close enough' to pi/2, _etc._, for these cases. On the definition for tan, I apologise: I am doing a maths degree in my spare time but have an unfortunate tendency to mix up sequences and series when thinking about limits! In the round, what I think is desirable is a return value for results which are not real numbers for whatever reason. To me, this makes most sense as 'undefined', but others may disagree.

Comment: I should add that I think that the LaTeX-L list might be a better place to hammer out any changes required to `l3fp`. As I've tried to make clear, nothing is set in stone.

Comment: @Joseph: I'd find it nice to distinguish "undefined" and "infinity" resp. "-infinity". But for the latter there are probably not many instances. For `\tan` in radians you don't need "undefined" at all since `\tan` is defined on all rational numbers, but the Cotangent is undefined at `0`.

Comment: @Hendrik: As I said, there is obviously discussion to be had on this, but I think {TeX} is perhaps not the best place for it (we're not exactly answering a focussed question!).

Comment: How about in our chat room? (pardon me...I'm still trying to find good uses for it)

Comment: @Yossi: and here I thought those things were added to SE specifically for the wasting of time!

Comment: @Joseph: in your example, the second `\fp_div:Nn` should be `\l_my_fp`.

Comment: @Joseph: If you're going to implement arctan, I recommend doing `atan2` from the C standard library since that is almost always more useful.

Comment: I think your goal should be implementing full IEEE arithmetic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating-point_arithmetic --- some of it is tricky, but, well, it's the IEEE sacred standard.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni That is the aim: Bruno Le FLoch has done a lot of work on this. At the point of writing, there are I believe some issues with subnormal numbers/underflows, but we should not be in a bad position. However, the standard leaves open some variability, which poses a few questions for TeX developers (for example in transcendental functions).